# How can capitalize 1st and 4th letter for more than one word in a string?

Tags: python, capitalize

I have solved the problem of how to capitalize the first and forth letter but out of curiosity I am trying to do that for all the words in a list rather than just the first:

```
def my_function(name):
    if len(name) > 3:
        return name[:3].capitalize() + name[3:].capitalize()
    else:
        return 'Name is too short'

result = my_function('oldmac')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply the same function for all the words in your list.

```
>>> def my_function(name):
...     if len(name) > 3:
...         return name[:3].capitalize() + name[3:].capitalize()
...     else:
...         return 'Name is too short'

>>> list_of_words = ['oldmac', 'newmac', 'latestmac']
>>> capitalized = [my_function(word) for word in list_of_words]
>>> capitalized
['OldMac', 'NewMac', 'LatEstmac']
```

Something like this.